# Js - window.open doesn´t exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.open

When i call **window.open** on my **angularjs aplication** i get this **error**

> TypeError: window.open is not a function

Then i call:

> console.log(window)

So, this is a image of console.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IVj3.png

I know if is relevant, but, this is the code:

```
$scope.ocPDF = function(){
  if($scope.oc.id){
    var width = window.innerWidth - 30;
    var url = 'whatever/' + $scope.oc.id;
    window.open(url, "name","menubar=1,resizable=1,width="+width+",height=500,top=80").focus();
  }
}
```

My question is. How can i **reset js** or what could be the cause of this? 
Its weird because in **others domains it works**. So its **not the browser.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `window.open` or just `open` isn't being assigned the boolean value somewhere. That's probably it :P

Comment: Omg, i enter in panic because it doesn't work in the meeting. I didnt even look in the new libraries i download... hahaha my bad. 

Thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem! Good luck on the meeting, and please don't forget to flag this as the answer to the question :) @MauriceLeOlavarriet